# JavaScript conditional array refactor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Lets say I have an array like this :

```
myArray = 
[
 {
  combineNext: false,
  title: 'Title1',
  items: [{item1},{item2}] 
 }, 
 {
  combineNext: true,
  title: 'Title2',
  items: [{item3}] 
 },
 {
  combineNext: true
  title: 'Title3',
  items: [{item4},{item5}] 
 },
 {
  combineNext: false
  title: 'Title4',
  items: [{item6}] 
 },
 {
  combineNext: true
  title: 'Title5',
  items: [{item7},{item8},{item9}] 
 }
]
```

I need to check where `combineNext` is true and concat the next array item (if exists) to it to create a new array of arrays like this:

```
theNewArrayofArrays = 
[
 [
  {
  combineNext: false,
  title: 'Title1',
  items: [{item1},{item2}] 
  }
 ], 
 [
  {
   combineNext: true,
   title: 'Title2',
   items: [{item3}] 
  },
  {
   combineNext: true
   title: 'Title3',
   items: [{item4},{item5}] 
  },
  {
   combineNext: false
   title: 'Title4',
   items: [{item6}] 
  },
 ],
 [
  {
   combineNext: true
   title: 'Title5',
   items: [{item7},{item8},{item9}] 
  }
 ]
]
```

What is the best way to have this output ?

Comment: Why is the first object in the result array?

Comment: I will map on the array of arrays after that so i will have 3 lists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `reduce` method and check previous element. If the previous element has `combineNext` true you add current element to last element in accumulator otherwise you push new array.

```js
const myArray = [{"combineNext":false,"title":"Title1"},{"combineNext":true,"title":"Title2"},{"combineNext":true,"title":"Title3"},{"combineNext":false,"title":"Title4"},{"combineNext":true,"title":"Title5"}]

const result = myArray.reduce((r, e, i, arr) => {
  const prev = arr[i - 1];
  if (prev && prev.combineNext) r[r.length - 1].push(e)
  else r.push([e])
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```